# n.s.j.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter : The supplied java.sql.Connection object is null

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a jrxml report file designed in jasper studio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Sample_Blue_Table_Based" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d4a1d5eb-82dd-412f-a620-202e4bdf9dba">
    <property name="template.engine" value="tabular_template"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="MyDBServer"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <style name="Table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Transparent" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Transparent" forecolor="#B89F7D" backcolor="#70A9C6">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Transparent" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="tableDataset" uuid="d126342f-2c37-4323-99a6-4d0a9542aa8a">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="MyDBServer"/>
        <queryString language="SQL">
            <![CDATA[select * from users]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="id"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="users"/>
        </field>
        <field name="created_at" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="created_at"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="users"/>
        </field>
        <field name="email" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="email"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="users"/>
        </field>
        <field name="firstName" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="firstName"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="users"/>
        </field>
        <field name="lastName" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="lastName"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="users"/>
        </field>
        <field name="updated_at" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="updated_at"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="users"/>
        </field>
        <field name="username" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="username"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="users"/>
        </field>
        <field name="status" class="java.lang.Boolean">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="status"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="users"/>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="72">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-20" y="-20" width="842" height="92" backcolor="#4AC416" uuid="6321f5e3-86eb-444f-acc1-8daaaa0d6c60"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="20" y="20" width="320" height="43" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="9e48917a-7b59-4ffd-baad-725f45563194"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="34" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Admin App Users]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="650" y="46" width="180" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="0a399baa-bad3-4b1a-9fe3-bb1c563e6a27"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="14" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Application Users Report]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="13"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="17">
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="4" width="515" height="13" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="fed27553-a6c4-4a8a-9056-2f6f2589a3e5"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="515" y="4" width="40" height="13" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="9f5ad531-d413-49c9-874b-8b99e8150fa6"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                <reportElement x="0" y="4" width="100" height="13" uuid="fc593335-5cbf-4caf-97b3-ff897c676bde"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="200" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="806" height="200" uuid="01fed4d0-1b62-44ff-9fa5-e47ff6987d68">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="tableDataset" uuid="2ad3f0b0-b1fd-40d9-a08f-170bf2519948">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="60" uuid="99ec822c-fb05-4f72-abd4-5f009620a549">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="60" height="30" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="06b3eded-dc90-4b57-9d0e-c51c6f342892"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement key="" x="0" y="0" width="60" height="30" uuid="19c36999-b01b-4bbd-a41e-c53ae0c80afd"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                                    <font fontName="Arial" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="140" uuid="2483833e-c55e-4a69-8868-9b08db7559c0">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column4"/>
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="30" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="9c786800-8901-47ae-bd4a-3c01204abd4d"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[First Name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement key="" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="30" uuid="d7b6cf06-c37f-4ec1-a519-3e7fe2d7be8b"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font fontName="Arial" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{firstName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="140" uuid="8d185e10-164e-420a-8a7f-d159ff9cb691">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column5"/>
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="30" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="946eda2c-149c-4eb4-a929-cca937fb6393"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Last Name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement key="" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="30" uuid="09d3f107-6c04-4587-bf7a-91e871ce4f3b"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font fontName="Arial" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{lastName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="130" uuid="395a497b-e0fc-4850-9f10-e41d4fd41035">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column6"/>
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="1912c136-2a05-4089-ae91-54a5d815bc92"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Username]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement key="" x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30" uuid="cb9efd41-06b7-4059-a6ec-0fb35ccdbbc2"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                                    <font fontName="Arial" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{username}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="160" uuid="3c37b453-c14e-41af-af30-696eac992472">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column3"/>
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="160" height="30" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="58e2962c-e1f6-4649-8bd3-3e410fa58674"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Email]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement key="" x="0" y="0" width="160" height="30" uuid="702a303c-9c29-4119-8156-8eb9bac28b7d"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                                    <font fontName="Arial" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{email}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="50" uuid="5a8d7002-6adc-4cff-9e7e-132ed9316b8e">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column7"/>
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="9ec69fab-1e14-49cf-ab25-1e8b037da361"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[A]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement key="" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" uuid="abfefc2d-93c3-4d65-afdc-5e9304224a32"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                                    <font fontName="Arial" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{status}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="120" uuid="1af5f085-9784-49d9-b3b8-17cf34f4ac84">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column2"/>
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="30" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="fd3401b4-a35c-435b-9c9c-9ba9840db3b8"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Created At]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement key="" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="30" uuid="9147c910-e8b4-4a79-8225-ea490c1de8a9"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font fontName="Arial" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{created_at}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

I followed the link here to integrate it with sprint boot app

[Jasper report in spring framework and spring JPA](http://learningprogramming.net/java/spring-mvc/jasper-report-in-spring-mvc-framework-and-spring-data-jpa/)

I have the following error when i run the app and a blank report.

Pleasssssssse help me integrate report generated from studio to spring boot.

(I am a java newbie)

here is my report controller method

```
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void report(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(userReportService.report());
        InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reports/users_report.jrxml");
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, dataSource);
        HtmlExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter(DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance());
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(response.getWriter()));
        exporter.exportReport();
    }
```

Am passing a json data as the data source

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely different technologies.

Comment: You are not passing the database connection when trying to export and all the java code where you are supposed to pass the connection to jasper reports is not included in question.

Comment: @PetterFriberg i just added my controller method

Comment: When I run the report in jasper studio, it was working correctly after setting up the data source there. what i dont get is how to edit the file to accept the json data source pass to it my controller

Comment: `<queryString language="SQL"><![CDATA[select * from users]]></queryString>` will not work if you are passing custom datasource, that would expect that you have a database connection

Comment: it worked in JasperSoft studio because you had an adapter..but it will not work outside if you don't pass the connection at least as a parameter.

Comment: @PetterFriberg do i have to edit the jrxml file to process the parameter sent to it or i can just include the parameters in the method call? thanks for you response

Comment: You need to pass the connection, personally if I was using a custom datasource for main report, I would do so as well for a subreport datasource. Hence I would load pass a list of beans to subreport, but yeah that's just my opinion.

Comment: @PetterFriberg thanks for sharing your opinion, it has pointed me in the right direction of finding the solution. i found an SO question that leads to the solution. I will be sharing the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345903/1597923) 
the steps as highlighted in the answer are:

1. Send your datasource from the server as a parameter, and fill the report with a different one (can be empty).
2. Declare a new parameter in the report of type JRBeanCollectionDataSource
3. Set TableDatasource to use the $P{DS1} parameter.
4. ...

In addition, i modified my report file field declarations and remove all jasper studio properties there.

After following this steps and modifying my report file and controller, it worked. Here is my new controller method:

```
public void report(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    List data = userReportService.report();
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(data);
    Map parameters = new HashMap();
    parameters.put("test", data.get(0));
    parameters.put("DS1", dataSource);
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reports/users_report.jrxml");
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
    HtmlExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter(DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance());
    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(response.getWriter()));
    exporter.exportReport();
}
```

And my new jrxml file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Sample_Blue_Table_Based" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d4a1d5eb-82dd-412f-a620-202e4bdf9dba">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <style name="Table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Transparent" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Transparent" forecolor="#B89F7D" backcolor="#70A9C6">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Transparent" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="tableDataset" uuid="d126342f-2c37-4323-99a6-4d0a9542aa8a">
        <queryString language="json">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="firstName" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="lastName" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="username" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="email" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="status" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
        <field name="created_at" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="DS1" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <title>
        <band height="72">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-20" y="-20" width="842" height="92" backcolor="#4AC416" uuid="6321f5e3-86eb-444f-acc1-8daaaa0d6c60"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="20" y="20" width="320" height="43" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="9e48917a-7b59-4ffd-baad-725f45563194"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="34" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Admin App Users]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="650" y="46" width="180" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="0a399baa-bad3-4b1a-9fe3-bb1c563e6a27"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="14" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Application Users Report]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="13"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="17">
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="4" width="760" height="13" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="fed27553-a6c4-4a8a-9056-2f6f2589a3e5"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="762" y="4" width="40" height="13" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="9f5ad531-d413-49c9-874b-8b99e8150fa6"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                <reportElement x="0" y="4" width="100" height="13" uuid="fc593335-5cbf-4caf-97b3-ff897c676bde"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="200" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="806" height="200" uuid="01fed4d0-1b62-44ff-9fa5-e47ff6987d68">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="tableDataset" uuid="ee7a04e1-1abd-4fc2-baf5-52183f1eaa43">
                        <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{DS1}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="60" uuid="99ec822c-fb05-4f72-abd4-5f009620a549">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="60" height="30" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="06b3eded-dc90-4b57-9d0e-c51c6f342892"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement key="" x="0" y="0" width="60" height="30" uuid="19c36999-b01b-4bbd-a41e-c53ae0c80afd"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Arial" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="140" uuid="2483833e-c55e-4a69-8868-9b08db7559c0">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column2"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="30" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="9c786800-8901-47ae-bd4a-3c01204abd4d"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[First Name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement key="" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="30" uuid="d7b6cf06-c37f-4ec1-a519-3e7fe2d7be8b"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Arial" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{firstName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="140" uuid="8d185e10-164e-420a-8a7f-d159ff9cb691">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column3"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="30" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="946eda2c-149c-4eb4-a929-cca937fb6393"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Last Name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement key="" x="0" y="0" width="140" height="30" uuid="09d3f107-6c04-4587-bf7a-91e871ce4f3b"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Arial" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{lastName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="130" uuid="395a497b-e0fc-4850-9f10-e41d4fd41035">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column4"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="1912c136-2a05-4089-ae91-54a5d815bc92"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Username]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement key="" x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30" uuid="cb9efd41-06b7-4059-a6ec-0fb35ccdbbc2"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Arial" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{username}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="160" uuid="3c37b453-c14e-41af-af30-696eac992472">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column5"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="160" height="30" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="58e2962c-e1f6-4649-8bd3-3e410fa58674"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Email]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement key="" x="0" y="0" width="160" height="30" uuid="702a303c-9c29-4119-8156-8eb9bac28b7d"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Arial" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{email}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="50" uuid="5a8d7002-6adc-4cff-9e7e-132ed9316b8e">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column6"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="9ec69fab-1e14-49cf-ab25-1e8b037da361"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[A]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement key="" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" uuid="abfefc2d-93c3-4d65-afdc-5e9304224a32"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Arial" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{status}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="120" uuid="1af5f085-9784-49d9-b3b8-17cf34f4ac84">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column7"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="30" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="fd3401b4-a35c-435b-9c9c-9ba9840db3b8"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Created At]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement key="" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="30" uuid="9147c910-e8b4-4a79-8225-ea490c1de8a9"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Arial" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{created_at}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

I hope this saves a newbie like me some headache and thanks to @PetterFriberg