# JasperReport using DataCollection

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to create a report using `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` but I have a problem. I need to print two records using checkboxes in a `JTable` but only one record is shown in JasperReport.

Here is my code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
    for(int j=0;j< model.getColumnCount();j++){
        Boolean value = (Boolean) model.getValueAt(i, 11);// check state
        if (value) {
            System.out.println(model.getValueAt(i, j));// second column value
            struk=new ArrayList<ListTrxPrint>();
            ListTrxPrint trx=new ListTrxPrint();
            trx.setId(model.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
            trx.setMsisdn(model.getValueAt(i, 4).toString());
            trx.setExecute_date(model.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
            trx.setNominal(model.getValueAt(i, 6).toString());
            trx.setSales_price(model.getValueAt(i,7).toString());
            trx.setUser_name(model.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
            struk.add(trx);
            bean=new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(struk);                       
        }
    }      
}

try{
    JasperDesign design=JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\Users\\PPS SAMSUL\\Documents\\RPTStruk.jrxml");
    JasperReport jReport=JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);               
    JasperPrint jPrint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jReport, null,bean);
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jPrint, false);
    JasperViewer.getWindows();              
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You need to show us the report itself, i.e. the `.jrxml` file.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/18787697/table-tool-in-showing-one-fewer-lesser-database-records/18822712

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `ArrayList` and `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` out of your loop, now you are **recreating them each time you loop**, furthermore I can not see any need to loop on all columns.

The code could be similar to:.

```
struk=new ArrayList<ListTrxPrint>();
for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
   Boolean value = (Boolean) model.getValueAt(i, 11);// check state
   if (value) {
       ListTrxPrint trx=new ListTrxPrint();
       trx.setId(model.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
       trx.setMsisdn(model.getValueAt(i, 4).toString());
       trx.setExecute_date(model.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
       trx.setNominal(model.getValueAt(i, 6).toString());
       trx.setSales_price(model.getValueAt(i,7).toString());
       trx.setUser_name(model.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
       struk.add(trx);
   }
 }      
 bean=new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(struk);
```

Comment: Thank you petter,...your answer is perfect,i am still need to learn more again.